# How to remove contact from Hangouts?

Tags: gmail, google-contacts, google-hangouts

I can't find anywhere an action to this. I need to remove the name of a dead person in my Hangouts contacts. I can only seem to Block or Hide a name.

Does anyone know how to remove the name altogether?
Any advice please on how to do this?